# How Can I return values from a class?

Tags: python

I have the following issue, I am trying to define a new class, and I have just created new methods an attributes, but when I try to return the values I have some issue like: "objects is not callable", "XXX is not an attribute of the class", etc. I imported all the libraries out of the class:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
(...)
```

Then just read the data:

```
charge = pd.read_csv('iris.csv',delimiter=';',decimal=",")
print(charge)
```

Then just decided to work with numeric variables as following:

```
data = charge.iloc[:, 0:4].values #
dataval= charge.iloc[:, 4].values
print(data)
print(dataval)
```

And everything looks great until this: when I defined my class

```
class mynew_ACP:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__data = data
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self.__data
    @datos.setter
    def data(self, data):
        self.__data = data
    def trasformation(self, data):
        col = StandardScaler().fit_transform(self.__data)
        col2= pd.DataFrame(col)
        return col2
    def correlation_var(self, data):
        corr = data.corr()
        return corr
```

But when I tried to call the methods to see the values I do not have anything. I have. tried with this code:

```
acp = mynew_ACP(data)
acp.data()
acp.trasformation()
acp.correlation_var()
```

Got error as mentioned in the beggining. I am new using Python and I do not know where is/are my issues. Tried with parenthesis and brackets but did not work.

Any help?

Comment: When you make it a `@property` you access it like a property: `some_name = scp.data` and `scp.data = some_value`

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. _Then just decided to work with numeric variables as following_ Why? Will using the Series directly not work? In any case, you should use `.to_numpy()` instead of `.values` if you're on a more recent version of Pandas. As an aside, the convention for class names is the `CamelCase` style.

Comment: Having setters/getters that merely access a private field, with no calculator or side-effects going on, is *utterly pointless* - just use a public field.  And note that the `.transformation()` and `.correlation_var()` cannot be called without any parameters, as you've defined them to take a `data` paremeter (in which case, what was the point of having any data stored in the class?).